# Jenkins error net.sf.json.JSONException: Invalid JSON String

Tags: json, jenkins

I am calling Powershell scripts via jenkins and I get output values from the powershell script and what seems to happen is that if the output value is null for whatever reason, the jenkins pipeline fails with the error below.

The code can be found below

```
     stage('Get Ticket Number') {
         steps {
             script {
                env.New_Ticket = powershell(returnStdout: true, script: '.\\New_Ticket.ps1')
             }
         }
     }
```

def ticket_json = readJSON text:"${env.New_Ticket}"
echo "Ticket: " + ticket_json.ticketno

The error details can be found below.

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: net.sf.json.JSONException: Invalid JSON String
    at net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(JSONSerializer.java:143)
    at net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(JSONSerializer.java:103)
    at net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(JSONSerializer.java:84)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.json.ReadJSONStepExecution.doRun(ReadJSONStepExecution.java:79)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.json.ReadJSONStepExecution.doRun(ReadJSONStepExecution.java:48)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.utility.steps.AbstractFileOrTextStepExecution.run(AbstractFileOrTextStepExecution.java:32)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this I was able to solve this by setting the `-encoding ASCII -NoNewline`.  I don't think the `-NoNewline` is required just the encoding being set.

Comment: could you share how to include this fix